# Counting with Venn Diagrams

Tags: combinatorics

How many arrangements are there of MURMUR with no pair of consecutive letters are the same.

This problem is from Alan Tucker's book: applied combinatorics.

Comment: Huh? You find the number where there are NOT two consecutive, and then subtract that from all possible ones?

Comment: Editted. Not sure how to go about it

Comment: One option would be to use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: Counting with venn diagrams?  What does this have to do with venn diagrams?

Answer (score 0):

Let's construct each arrangement of MURMUR without lose of generality. Let $L_n$ be the $n$-th letter in an arrangement.

(1) $L_1$ has 6 options.

(2) $L_2$ has 4 options, since it can't be the same as $L_1$.

(3) $L_3$ has 3 options, since it can't be the same as $L_2$. However, these options are broken up by (4).

(4) $L_4$ is broken up into two possibilities:

1. If $L_3 = L_1$ (can happen 1 way), then $L_4$ has 2 options since we have 3 letters left to use, 2 of them are the same, and none of them are $L_3$. Thus we need $L_4 = L_6$, which can happen 2 ways. Additionally, $L_5$ and $L_6$ are both locked into 1 option.
2. If $L_3 \neq L_1$ (can happen 2 ways), $L_4$ has 2 options since it can't be the same as $L_3$. Consequently, $L_5$ has 2 options and $L_6$ is locked into 1 option.

Putting all of this together we get the number of arrangements to be
$$6 \cdot 4 \cdot [1\cdot (2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1) + 2 \cdot (2 \cdot 2 \cdot 1)]=240.$$
However, these arrangements aren't unique, we counted twice for each letter M, U, and R. So the number of unique arrangements comes out to be
$$\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 240 = 30.$$
I did verify this with Python, just to double check.

Answer (score 0):

First letter is one of $3$. Let's call it $A$. Second letter is then one of $2$, let's call it $B$. Now, if third letter is same as first ($ABA$) then the rest of word is forced ($ABACBC$). If third letter is different from first ($ABC$) then $4$ options ($ABCABC$, $ABCACB$, $ABCBAC$, $ABCBCA$).

Total: $3\cdot 2 \cdot (1+4)=30$